# picker view with button to go to next page

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to do a pickerView and a button which when you choose your option in pickerView it goes to the relevant page.

So far I've got to the point when you choose the option in picker view it goes to the relevant page, but what I want is choose and then click on the button to go to the page.

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

var selection = ["Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self


}

@IBAction func SelectionBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    } 



func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return selection.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let selected = selection[row]

    return selected
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {



    if (row == 0) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "red", sender: self)
    }
    else if (row == 1) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "blue", sender: self)
    }
    else {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "green", sender: self)

        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Take an extra variable to store information on regarding which row you have selected.

```
var rowSelected:Int! = -1
```

Store the selected row to this variable.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
 rowSelected = row
}
```

During button action check the variable to perform desired Segue.

```
@IBAction func actSegue(sender:Any){
    if row == 0 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "red", sender: self)
    }...
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row selected with :`pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)`

```
@IBAction func SelectionBtn(_ sender: Any) {
 let rowSelected = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
 if (rowSelected == 0) {

performSegue(withIdentifier: "red", sender: self)
}
else if (rowSelected == 1) {

performSegue(withIdentifier: "blue", sender: self)
}
else {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "green", sender: self)

    }
}
```